# Running pytorch or tensorflow in AMD APU

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, gpu, archlinux, amd-gpu

I have a machine with a AMD Radeon APU: gfx90c
I am using arch linux.

I have been battling to get the PyTorch and TensorFlow to use the APU, but so far no results.
I already tried to build the arch packages of tensorflow romc and nothing.
Anyone with any idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ArchLinux:
https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/79620

Everyone else, September 2023, ROCM does not support AMD APU.
So not possible to use pytorch or tensorflow in AMD APU.